# "Был миллион вопросов" или "было миллион вопросов"?

Tags: окончания

Спорю с другом о том, как правильно ставить окончание в слове "было". Какой из вариантов является верным? Мне кажется, что первый вариант правильный.

1. У него был**о** миллион вопросов
2. У него был миллион вопросов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. А вот пример согласования **в среднем роде**:

Разумеется, трудностей и скептиков **было миллион**, но он все мужественно преодолел. [Игорь Свинаренко,  1997.08.12]

2. Сравнить: У него был миллион рублей (**точное количество**).

У него было миллион вопросов (**много вопросов**).

Во втором примере "миллион" обозначает ****приблизительную оценку**.**

3. Таким образом, возможно как формальное согласование, так и согласование по смыслу, и на слух эта семантика различается. Поэтому и существуют разные мнения: одни люди чувствуют **разный смысл**, а другие на такие вещи не обращают внимания.

Розенталь же говорит, что "при словах тысяча, миллион, миллиард сказуемое **обычно** согласуется по правилам согласования с подлежащими-существительными (в роде и числе)".  Обычно, но не всегда.

4. Отметим, что при согласовании "было миллион"  на первом месте стоит сказуемое. в этом случае отсутствие формального грамматического согласования  **менее заметно.**

Answer (score 2):

Второй вариант. По «миллиону» согласуем.
«При словах *тысяча, миллион, миллиард* сказуемое обычно согласуется по правилам согласования с подлежащими-существительными (в роде и числе), например: ***Тысяча** книг **поступила** в школьную библиотеку; **Миллион** демонстрантов **заполнил** площади и улицы столицы».*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой   Артём, вы убрали закрывающие кавычки, а открывающие оставили. Это, видимо, цитата, ссылку на которую автор ответа не привел.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: ой, спасибо, Александр! Я с телефона смотрел и показалось, что открывающие кавычки были перед *тысячей* и их убрал предлагающий правку. А оказалось, что они в начале абзаца. :)